# How to interpret this SQL Server error message

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am executing a stored proc from SSMS and I get this error message:

```
Msg 295, Level 16, State 3, Procedure spEdiCreateOrders, Line 80 [Batch Start Line 2]
Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type.
```

Of course I could try and err, but I'd like to be able to take advantage of the message, and I am a bit perplexed by the message.
'`line 80`': starting from where ? From the `BEGIN` clause of the `Alter procedure` ? Or does it really refer to the line 80 I see when I click `Modify` ?
Also, what does `Batch Start Line 2` mean ?
Thx !

---

**edit**: note that I am NOT interested in help solving the issue (it is already solved). I just want a clear guidelines about how to interpret 'line 80' and 'Batch Start Line 2', so that next time I immediately know where to look at.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if you are trying to figure out why the error is occurring or if that is clear to you and you only want help with the messages and their context. If its the error it's probably the parameter value you are passing into your Stored Proc, can you check that value?

Comment: @Igor no parameter provided. I KNOW the issue is in the `INSERT`statement starting at line 97 in the screenshot, but I would find useful for myself and others to clearly interpret those error messages.

Comment: Using `print` you could write various messages to the output. Is there anything before that would print a custom message which is then later displayed if there is an error and makes it appear like it is part of the error when it is not?

Comment: @Igor that's what I do. And that's how I know where it crashed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When looking at the code of a stored procedure using the *Alter procedure*, the error line is from the BEGIN command, as the error occurred in the procedure, not in the *Alter procedure* command

- BEGIN = line 0
- next line (the actual start of the procedure = 1
- etc

Batch line 2 means the second batch of statements - this means you have a `GO` somewhere in the procedure, and this is in the second set of statements (http://sqlhints.com/tag/examples-of-sql-go-statement/), the first set appearing before the `GO`

Comment: I just tested, Batch Start Line 2 actually means you have a "GO" command in the 2nd line, so the current batch start from line 2.

Answer (score 2):

About `Line n`

`N` it is refer to the number of line of object considering any spaces with in it , or before its body.

**Example 1**

Assume the next is SQLQuery window after clicking **New Query** button in `SSMS`

```
1. Create proc spTest1

2. As

3. Begin

4. Select 1/0

5. End
```

after executing  `spTest1`, you will get the next message

> Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spTest1, Line 4

**Example 2**

Assume the next is SQLQuery window after clicking **New Query** button in `SSMS`

```
1. 

2.

3.

4.

5.

6. Create proc spTest2

7. As

8. Begin

9. Select 1/0

10. End
```

after executing  `spTest2`, you will get the next message

> Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spTest2, Line 9

**Conclusion how get the accurate number**

For getting the accurate number use the system stored procedure `sp_helptext` as next

```
Exec sp_helptext spName
```

Comment: when looking at the procedure using an Alter command, then you need to look at the code of the procedure itself, not the extra parts SQL Server put in place to allow you to edit the procedure