# How to interpret T-SQL error incorrect syntax near

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I don't quite follow how to interpret the T-SQL error messages with regards to line numbers and "Batch Start Line".

When I try to run the `CREATE PROCEDURE`, I get the following errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure LoadIndexersReports, Line 119 [Batch Start Line 9]
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure LoadIndexersReports, Line 120 [Batch Start Line 9]
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

When I go to line 119, it is code that I know should be good, because I copy-pasted the code, so I decide to comment out the whole block.

I still get the same error, but all line around 119 are actually commented out.

How am I supposed to interpret this?

Any clues as to the weird way in which T-SQL is reporting errors?

I can probably widdle it down and figure out what the problem is.

That's not the question.

I'm puzzled by how stupid and meaningless the line reference seems to be, and if there is a way to fix that.

Here is the complete code pasted starting line 1 with [USE] statement:

```
USE [QtyCompare]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[LoadRecentlyIndexed]    Script Date: 10/10/2018 1:01:02 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[LoadIndexersReports] 
     @StartDate DATE, @DaysForward INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    --  IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TempRecentlyIndexedRaw'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DELETE FROM dbo.TempRecentlyIndexedRaw

    DECLARE @pLastModified DATETIME,
            @pPONO VARCHAR(50),
            @pProduct VARCHAR(100),
            @pQuantity VARCHAR(15),
            @pHeat VARCHAR(25),
            @pProduct_Description VARCHAR(250),
            @pSerial_Or_Lot VARCHAR(50),
            @pCoreData_IID_ssField14 INT,
            @pDocId INT,
            @pIndexers VARCHAR(200),
            @pAR_Alpha VARCHAR(50),
            @pValve BIT,
            @tempString VARCHAR(500),
            @pARs VARCHAR(250)   /*sorted ALPHABETICALLY, ASCENDING ... Note:  ABC234 > ABC1111, because its sorted ALPHABETICALLY */

    -- If Documents were deleted, remove them from your ocean
    DELETE IH
    FROM IndexHistory IH
    LEFT JOIN IndexedLineItems LI ON IH.Docid = LI.DocId
    WHERE LI.DocId IS NULL

    -- *************************************************************************************
    -- * B.
    -- PULL FROM RAW, CREATE TempRecentlyIndexed
    -- 
    -- *************************************************************************************

    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TempRecentlyIndexed', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
         DROP TABLE dbo.TempRecentlyIndexed;

    SELECT * 
    INTO TempRecentlyIndexed 
    FROM IndexHistory 
    WHERE LastModified >= @StartDate 
      AND [LastModified] <= CAST(DATEADD(dd, @DaysForward - 1, GETDATE()) AS DATE)

-- *************************************************************************************
    -- * C.  Generate your reports from TempRecentlyIndexed
    -- 
    -- 
    -- *************************************************************************************

    --lines summary
    SELECT 
        Indexers, SUM(LinesIndexed) AS [Total Lines Indexed], 
        SUM(LinesFactoringInValvesTTLHeats) AS [Total Lines Indexed Factoring In Valves (Multiple Heats)]  
    FROM
        (SELECT
             Indexers, AR_Alpha, 
             COUNT(*) AS LinesIndexed, SUM([Heat Items]) AS LinesFactoringInValvesTTLHeats 
         FROM
             (SELECT 
                  LastModified, PONO, Product, Quantity, 
                  IIF(Charindex('Valve Heats', Heat) > 0, CAST(Replace(Heat, ' Valve Heats', '') AS INT), 1) AS [Heat Items], 
                  DocId, Indexers, AR_Alpha 
              FROM
                  [dbo].[TempRecentlyIndexed] 
              WHERE
                  product IS NOT NULL) AS AAA
         GROUP BY 
             AR_Alpha, Indexers) PreviousQuery
    GROUP BY
        Indexers
    ORDER BY
        Indexers

    --documents
    Select Indexers, Count(*) as [Documents Indexed] from 
    (
    Select distinct Docid, Indexers from [dbo].[TempRecentlyIndexed] where Product is not null
    ) as AAA
    group by Indexers
    order by Indexers

    --lines detail
    select Indexers, AR_Alpha, Count(*) as [Lines Indexed], Sum([Heat Items]) as [Total Lines Indexed Factoring In Valves (Multiple Heats)] from 
    (
    SELECT LastModified, PONO, Product, Quantity, IIF(Charindex('Valve Heats',Heat)>0,Cast(Replace(Heat,' Valve Heats','') as int),1) as [Heat Items], DocId, Indexers, AR_Alpha from [dbo].[TempRecentlyIndexed] where product is not null
    ) as AAA
    group by AR_Alpha, Indexers 
    order by Indexers, AR_Alpha




-- *************************************************************************************
    -- * D.  Generate summaries for comparison with Arrivals data
    -- 
    -- 
    -- *************************************************************************************

    -- Recently Indexed Summary
--  IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TempRecentlyIndexedSummary', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
--    DROP TABLE dbo.TempRecentlyIndexedSummary;
--
--  select LastModified, Product, sum(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Quantity + 'e0') = 1 THEN CAST(Quantity AS float) ELSE 0 END) AS Quantity, Indexers, AR_Alpha, ARs
--  into TempRecentlyIndexedSummary
--  from TempRecentlyIndexed
--  where product is not null
--  Group by LastModified,Product,INdexers,AR_Alpha,ARs


-- *************************************************************************************
    -- * D2.  Load Related Records
    -- 
    -- 
    -- *************************************************************************************


    Delete from dbo.TempRelatedIndexedRaw
    Delete from dbo.TempRelatedIndexed
    SELECT distinct ARs into #ARList FROM [dbo].[IndexHistory] WHERE [LastModified] <= cast( dateadd(dd,@DaysForward-1,@StartDAte) as date) AND [LastModified] >= @StartDate)
    Select * into TempRelatedIndexed from IndexHistory left Join #ARList on IndexHistory.ARs = #ARList.ARs where Not([LastModified] <= cast( dateadd(dd,@DaysForward-1,@StartDAte) as date) AND [LastModified] >= @StartDate))



    -- Summary to include both recently indexed and related indexed
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TempIndexedSummary', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
      DROP TABLE dbo.TempIndexedSummary;

    Select Product, Sum(Quantity) as Quantity, AR_Alpha, ARs into TempIndexedSummary from
    (Select * from TempRecentlyIndexedSummary
    Union All
    Select * from TempRelatedIndexedSummary) CombinedSummaries
    group by Product, AR_Alpha, ARs 


    --exec [dbo].[LoadRecentlyIndexedARSets]


    --Arrival Summary
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TempArrivalSummary', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
      DROP TABLE dbo.TempArrivalSummary;

    Select AProdNo as Product, Sum(QTY) as Quantity, ARs into TempArrivalSummary from
    (
    select RA.*, ARSets.[Set] as ARs from 
    (Select * from Raw_Arrival Union All Select * from Arrivals_2017 ) RA
    left join [IndexHistoryARSets] ARSets on RA.ARsupp = ARSets.AR 
    where RA.TrueBOSTK = 'STK' and (ARSets.[Set] is not null)
    ) Arrivals
    group by AProdNo, ARs


    -- *************************************************************************************
    -- * E.  Generate DISCREPENCY report based on summary
    -- 
    -- 
    -- *************************************************************************************

    --Generate Discrepency Report
    select Coalesce(TAS.Product,'<No Data>') as Arrival_Product, Coalesce(TAS.ARs,'<No Data>') Arrival_ARs, Coalesce(TAS.Quantity ,0) as Arrival_Qty, Coalesce(TIS.Quantity  ,0) as Indexed_Qty, Coalesce(TIS.Product   ,'<No Data>') as Ndx_Product, Coalesce(TIS.ARs ,'<No Data>') as Ndx_ARs,
    Coalesce((Select top 1 Indexers from TempRecentlyIndexed TRI where TRI.ARs = TIS.ARs), '<No Data>')
    from
    TempArrivalSummary TAS FULL OUTER JOIN TempIndexedSummary TIS
    on TAS.Product = TIS.Product and TAS.ARs = TIS.ARs


    -- *************************************************************************************
    -- * E.  Generate Pivot table data
    -- 
    -- 
    -- *************************************************************************************

    --THIS IS YOUR PIVOT SET FOR HARSHAL
    Select PivotMain.*, Coalesce(PivotAdditional.Country,'Unknown') as Country, Coalesce(PivotAdditional.[Assigned Indexer], 'Undefined') as [Assigned Indexer], Replace(Coalesce(PivotAdditional.Automated,''),'X','YES') as Automated, Coalesce(PivotAdditional.Domestic,'') as Domestic, PivotAdditional.[Line Items Recieved To Date] as [Relative Volume] from
    (Select Indexers, 1 as Lines, iif(Charindex('Valve Heats', Coalesce(Heat,''), 0)>0,Cast(RTrim(LTrim(Replace(Heat,'Valve Heats',''))) as int),1) as [Lines Factoring In Valves], Docid, LastModified, AR_Alpha as Supplier, iif(Charindex('.', AR_Alpha)=2,RIGHT(ar_ALPHA,LEN(ar_aLPHA)-2),AR_Alpha) as Suffix, ARs from [dbo].[TempRecentlyIndexed]) PivotMain
    left join Suffix PivotAdditional on (PivotMain.Supplier = PivotAdditional.Supplier and PivotMain.Suffix = PivotAdditional.Suffix)



End
GO
```

Comment: so, just to be clear, you are not asking how to fix your code, but why the error message is what it is and how to get a more meaningful one?. If so, I don't think that that's something we can answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to interpret this SQL Server error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41165373/how-to-interpret-this-sql-server-error-message)

Comment: yeah, its pretty common.  I run into it all the time.  Just wondering if anybody has developed insight into this.  I would wait and see if someone with alot of experience has an answer to this.  I think it has some value.  If no answer,  you can delete post if you like.

Comment: It’s a well written question; I just think it was answered by the other one. Although squillman’s tip below is a good one.

Comment: You expect us to count down 119 lines?

Comment: yeah, in a way the question was asked before, but keep this post, we have a valuable additional answer below.  double click on the error in ssms.  simple, but I didn't know it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line numbers in errors are very frequently mismatched between a SSMS query window and what the SQL interpreter reports.  The interpreter reports the line number relative to the statement being executed in the batch.  If you have multiple batches (typically separated by GO) such as you do then the line number in the exception will be off from what the line numbers show in your query window.

In SSMS you can double-click on the error message in the Results pane and SSMS will put your cursor on the statement causing the error.

In your example, the line throwing the error is this:
`SELECT distinct ARs into #ARList FROM [dbo].[IndexHistory] WHERE [LastModified] <= cast( dateadd(dd,@DaysForward-1,@StartDAte) as date) AND [LastModified] >= @StartDate)`

This statement has one too many `)`'s.  Delete the one at the end to fix the syntax in that line.  Also note that the very next statement has the same problem.  You'll need to fix both statements.

Answer (score 1):

When we have a lot of code, probably in those cases we can have a sintax error.

The more simple way to get the error is double click at the error, and SQL Management will take you to the line you must check no matter line numbers.

[image]

Comment: same point as above, but well-illustrated and stands out quickly.  thx.