# SQL Server: how to find the specific line of failing code based on [Batch Line Start] error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Often while running procedures in Microsoft SQL Server, I will get an error message like the following:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure XYZ, LineAss 88 [Batch Start Line 2]

However, Line 88 as specified in `LineAss 88` won't actually contain any code related to the error. Also it is typically unclear what `Batch Line Start #` refers to.

What methodology do you use based on the batch and line number to actually identify the specific code that is the problem when debugging failing procedures?

Comment: Check this link out: https://www.sqlshack.com/debugging-stored-procedures-sql-server-management-studio-ssms/

Comment: @CR7SMS thank you for the link!  This will be very helpful.  With regard to the question at hand, do you if the line LineAss and Batch Start Line actually refer to anything useful?

Comment: Is that the complete error message...It seems awfully short ;)

Comment: @CR7SMS that is not the entire error.  I specifically left off the rest of the error because I'm sheerly interested if anyone has info with regard to ```LineAss 88 [Batch Start Line 2]```.  It would be very useful if SSMS actually put the correct line in the error code

Comment: Finally understood your question, I posted an answer. Give it a read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a while to understand your question completely. The line number mentioned in the error message does not point to the exact line in which error occurred. It points to the statement in which the error occurred. Another thing to note is that, in your stored procedure, if you have blank rows at the beginning of the query, they will be added into the line count. This sometimes throws off the line number which you see in the error message as well.

I also found an interesting read on this topic:

http://tomaslind.net/2013/10/15/line-numbers-in-t-sql-error-messages/

This should be able to clarify most of your doubts. Let me know if you need further clarifications.

Comment: Batch line 2 means that the error is in the second batch of statements. This likely means you have a GO somewhere in the procedure, and this is in the second set of statements.

Comment: found another question similar to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41165373/how-to-interpret-this-sql-server-error-message

Comment: Thank you @CR7SMS this is very helpful.  What do you think Batch Line refers to if there are 3 ```Go``` statements in the procedure as below:  ```USE [TICF_ALM_PRD]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[BOOKVALUE_AND_BUDETAILS]    Script Date: 3/4/2020 5:00:58 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE```

Comment: Batch 3 would be : `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON`...batches are executed by SQL separately...here's a read on that: https://sqlhints.com/tag/examples-of-sql-go-statement/

Answer (score 0):

Do "Alter definition".

It seems to start from the `GO` line in the Stored Procedure, which it treats as line zero.

E.g., I got an error:

> Msg 1205, Level 13, State 78, Procedure dbo.xxx, Line 678 [Batch Start Line 2]

The `GO` was on line 7 and, when I tracked it down, it was line 600 in the file.

Comment: I'm confused. If the `GO` line is on 7, and the error says line 678, I'd expect that the error would be on line 685, but you're saying it's on line 600. Are you sure you got your line numbers correct in your example?